What are студенческие блины?
In Шум времени by Osip Mandelstam we have the following sentence:

Тысяча  девятьсот  пятый год - химера русской революции  с жандармскими рысьими глазками  и в голубом студенческом  блине!

I know that блины are pancakes, but they are not blue, so I am wondering if студенческие блины don't denote something else.

Блин here is a metaphor for фуражка "forage cap", a wide flat cap decorated with a blue band that was a part of students' uniform in the Russian Empire and other European countries.
These caricatures by the Russian artist  Vladimir Kadulin will give you the idea of what these caps looked like:



In general, блин is a popular metaphor for something wide, flat, and round. Weight plates for barbells, heating elements on electric cooktops, shock-absorbing pads on railroad car buffers, and many other things are informally or semi-formally called блины.

What a brilliant answer! And nice examples!
